# hour() function of excel in postgres (equivalent)

Tags: postgresql, excel-formula, equivalent

I am working recently with postgres and I have to make several calculations. However I have not been able to imitate the HOUR () function of Excel, I read the [official information](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hour-function-a3afa879-86cb-4339-b1b5-2dd2d7310ac7) but it did not help me much.

The function receives a decimal and obtains the hour, minutes and seconds of the same, example the decimal 0,99988426 returns 11:59:50. Try doing this in postgres (i use PostgreSQL 10.4) with the to_timestamp function: select to_char (to_timestamp (0.99988426), 'HH24: MI: SS'); this return 19:00:00. Surely I am omitting something, some idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
24:00:00 or 86400 seconds = 1 
Half day(12:00 noon) or 43200 seconds = 43200/86400 = 0.5
11:59:50 or 86390 seconds = 86390/86400 = 0.99988426
```

So to convert your decimal value to time, all you have to do is multiply it with 86400 which will give you seconds and convert it to your format in following ways:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((0.99988426 * 86400) * '1 second'::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS');

SELECT (0.99988426 * 86400) * interval '1 sec';
```

Comment: +1. You can go directly to the day interval `SELECT TO_CHAR(0.99988426  * '1 day'::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS');`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, now I know how this works. regards

Answer (score 0):

There are two major differences to handle:

Excel does not consider the time zone. The serial date 0 starts at 0h00, but Postgres uses the time zone so it becomes 19h. You would need to use UTC in Postgres result to have the same as in Excel.

```sql
select to_char (to_timestamp (0), 'HH24: MI: SS'),to_char (to_timestamp (0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24: MI: SS');
  to_char   |  to_char
------------+------------
 19: 00: 00 | 00: 00: 00
```

Excel considers that 1 is one day, while Postgres considers 1 as 1 second. To get the same behavior, multiply your number by the 86400, i.e. the number of seconds in a day

```sql
select to_char (to_timestamp (0.99988426*86400) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24: MI: SS');
  to_char
------------
 23: 59: 50
(1 row)
```

Comment: `while Postgres sets it at 19h ` Uh... what ?

Comment: @leonbloy `select to_char (to_timestamp (0), 'HH24: MI: SS')` --> 19h00

Comment: This answer is wrong. `to_timestamp (0)` returns the start time of Unix epoch (1 January 1970, 00:00:00) . This recipes gets the right answer just because it's using a particular timezone (GMT-4). It's bad practice to depend on that. I get a different result in my timezone `select to_char (to_timestamp (0), 'HH24: MI: SS') --> 21h00 `

Comment: To fix this answer: `select (to_timestamp (0.99988426*86400) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' )::time`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I knew that I need to multiply by a value, but I did not know que valor.